# PHP - Display the random number and the day of the week in all 5 iterations

Tags: php

Hi I trying to do the following task:
I used many array functions to accomplish the task with no success. Used inner for loop as well no results cant bring back the weekday element correctly.

Write code to initialise an associative array with keys from 1 to 7 and values representing days of the week (Sunday to Saturday). Write a do while loop that iterates 5 times. In each iteration, it should generate a random number between 1 and 7. Use the random number as the key to access the correct array element to obtain the correct day of the week.

This is my code so far:

```
$i = 0;
$weekday = array(); // Create Array
$weekday['1'] = 'Sunday';
$weekday['2'] = 'Monday';
$weekday['3'] = 'Tuesday';
$weekday['4'] = 'Wednesday';
$weekday['5'] = 'Thursday';
$weekday['6'] = 'Friday';
$weekday['7'] = 'Saturday';
    do {
    $num_rang=range(1,7); // range 1 to 7
    $result_array = array_combine($num_rang, $weekday); // Trying to combine arrays
    shuffle($num_rang); //random number range
    for ($x=0; $x< 1; $x++)
    {
     echo $num_rang[$x].' '; //display the Random number and Weekday corresponding to the number
    }
```

Comment: Instead of all this, simply use [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) function.

Answer (score 3):

It's simple. See the documentation about [PHP rand](http://php.net/manual/es/function.rand.php) and [PHP do-while](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.do.while.php)

```
#  initialise an associative array with keys from 1 to 7
$weekday = array();
$weekday['1'] = 'Sunday';
$weekday['2'] = 'Monday';
$weekday['3'] = 'Tuesday';
$weekday['4'] = 'Wednesday';
$weekday['5'] = 'Thursday';
$weekday['6'] = 'Friday';
$weekday['7'] = 'Saturday';

$i = 0;

do {

    # random number between 1 and 7
    $random = rand(1,7);

    echo $weekday[$random]."<br/>";

    $i++;

} while ($i < 5);
```

Comment: for what reason you use a `do...while` instead of a `for` loop (that is designed to count iterations)?

Comment: I use do-while because the user said "Write a do while loop that iterates 5 times". I would have used a for loop too.

Comment: @JGrinon: Indeed, I didn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution is:

```
$i = 0;
$weekday = array(); // Create Array
$weekday['1'] = 'Sunday';
$weekday['2'] = 'Monday';
$weekday['3'] = 'Tuesday';
$weekday['4'] = 'Wednesday';
$weekday['5'] = 'Thursday';
$weekday['6'] = 'Friday';
$weekday['7'] = 'Saturday';
while ($i < 5) {
    echo $weekday[rand(1,7)];
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$weekday = array_combine(
    range(1,7),
    ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
);

$i = 5;
do {
    $key = mt_rand(1,7);
    echo $key, "\t", $weekday[$key], PHP_EOL;
} while (--$i);
```

When `$i` is equal to 0, the condition is evaluated to `false` and the loop stops. Note that `$i` is decremented before the condition is evaluated since the `--` operator is placed before `$i`.

I used `mt_rand` instead of `rand` since this function is faster. [Read more about it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php).